# How can I replace data in a sharepoint 2010 table if ID matches?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I've tried to write a javascript element to get this running. Here's my effort so far:

```
if(filename == "DashboardReportList" || filename == "DashboardReportEdit")  {

    var found = false;

    for (var i=0; i < DashboardReportList.length; i++) {
        if (CalendarWeekNumber in DashboardReportList[i]) {
            DashboardReportList[i][CalendarWeekNumber ] = count;
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!found)
    {
        var tmp = {};
        tmp[CalendarWeekNumber] = count;
        DashboardReportList.push(tmp);
    }
}
```

I have 52 entries for data updates for the year, then when the next year starts I want to replace the older data entries so they don't all show up on the form
Edit: Looking back, I dind't explain it well enough.

We add these in through a form so when they get added through the form I want them to replace the old weeks from the previous year.

Comment: We may need a bit more context to help you. What are DashboardReportList and CalendarWeekNumber? Are you trying to change an HTML table, change what displays to the end user on a custom page/form, or actually update items in a SharePoint list?

Comment: Hey Thriggle. Sorry for only seeing this now. DashboardReportList is the Sharepoint list and CalendarWeekNumber is the data value inside the table that I don't want repeating itself. I'm trying to change what displays for the end user.

Comment: So to be sure I understand: 1. Users create one item in the SharePoint list for each week of each year (52 weeks per year). 2. You only want to show the 52 most recent entries, hiding the older ones, such that only one entry appears for each week.